# Blender Object Glowing in Dark with no Emission Shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, error, emission

For some reason an object in my scene glows in the dark no matter what I do (including removing all its materials) any suggestions?
[image]

[EDIT]
Here's what happens when the materials are removed:
[image: nomat]

Comment: Check your World settings as well as the world/environment shading

Comment: throw the .blend file on here please - not enough info to be gleaned from the two images...